# Is it OK for a web app to refresh itself when server is pushing the update?

Tags: mobile, user-interface, notifications, user-experience, page-refresh

Basically, we are building a small apps for mobile that list and display all applications/builds/details availables on the server. The listing is between 3-25 apps and each apps on the display occupy about 60 pixel hight with nice UI.

Apps 1 version ABC build date...
Details of the apps here (1-100 lines)

Apps 2 version ABC build  date...
Details of the apps here (1-100 lines)

Apps 3 version ABC build  date...
Details of the apps here (1-100 lines)

Apps 4 version ABC build  date...
Details of the apps here (1-100 lines)

etc.

The listing order/size may change few times during a day (1-3). Is it good practice the just update the listing without any warning?

We have concerns if user is reading details for exemple while the refresh occured, the refresh will cause a scroll back to top. etc. We are talking about "good practice" of apps behavior.

Any comment or suggestion would be appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think it's all right to refresh data on an application if the goal of the application is to show the most actual data at all times.
 But it is VERY important to give a clear and noticeable feed back to the user that the data has been refreshed, with an animation, some color changing or just an effect that goes well with the application.

Another option (and you have a great example just here in Browser Stack) is to tell the user that there is new data, and make them do something to update it.

Like a small prompt at the top of the screen that says "New data is available, tap here to update". That way you are sure that the user is 100% aware that data is being pushed to the application again, and that he agrees to do it.

Hope this helps.